# Approximation of a series containing Bessel functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, special-functions, bessel-functions

I have this series:
$$\displaystyle S=\sum_{k=0}^N\left(J_k(x)-J_k(y)\right)$$
where:
$J_k(\dot{})$ is the Bessel function of order $k$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$.
I have to calculate this series for $N\approx 4000$.
Can I use some semplification in order to express the Bessel function in a way useful for speed numerical evaluation?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since for every $k\geq 1$ we have: 
$$\frac{d}{dx} J_k(x) = \frac{J_{k-1}(x)-J_{k+1}(x)}{2} $$
it follows that:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} S &=& J_0(x)-J_0(y)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{y}^{x}\frac{J_{k-1}(t)-J_{k+1}(t)}{2}\,dt\\&=&J_0(x)-J_0(y)+\frac{1}{2}\int_{y}^{x}\left(J_0(t)+J_1(t)-J_n(t)-J_{n+1}(t)\right)\,dt\end{eqnarray*} $$
and the latter is easier to evaluate since it involves only four different Bessel functions instead of $n$.